# why is .htaccess not working on live site?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm needing to rewrite urls to be "pretty" instead of queries: they need to be /kw/blah instead of kw.php?kw=blah. I've tested the code several times with online checkers, and they say it works/is syntactically correct.

The two sites I used to check are: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be (url testing was with /kw/melbourne-web-design and http://www.htaccesscheck.com

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blueshiftwebservices\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://blueshiftwebservices.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^kw/([^/]*)$ landing.php?kw=$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm getting an error of 404 Page not found only with the pretty url, not the url that contains the query.

The live site definitely refers to the .htaccess file, so I'm lost at what to do?

Comment: you need to enable mod_rewrite in apache, did you already do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` matches all URLs. So you must insert the rule `RewriteRule ^kw/([^/]*)$ landing.php?kw=$1 [L]` before it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # redirect to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blueshiftwebservices\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://blueshiftwebservices.com/$1 [R,L]

    # are you sure you need it?
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # make it "pretty"
    RewriteRule ^kw/([^/]*)$ landing.php?kw=$1 [L]

    # process the rest
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Placing the RewriteRule where you said fixed it!